# CGAffineTrasformRotation also rotates the coordinating system

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform, coordinate-systems

I am rotating a `UIView` and then adding a new `UIView` to it. But it looks really weird.

Here is how it looks. The red box is the thing thats not as I expected.

[image]

I want the red box to be in the same direction as the blue box.

Im rotating the `UIView` like this:

```
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90))];
```

And then adding the red box as a `UIView` the normal way.

Im thinking that this is just the way transformations work and Im wondering if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: Correct. A rotate transform applied to a view rotates the view's coordinate system. How did you think it worked?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior if you're adding the red box *after* you perform the rotate. If you want the red box to have the same transformation as the blue one, then you'll need add the red box as its subview before applying the rotation transformation.

Comment: Your right, another question I have. I first create a CGRect which Im going to use later and then add the UIView with that frame just to see it, will this CGRect also rotate? Ex. if I have a rect (0,0,40,20) will it be a (0,0,20,40) after the rotate?

Comment: That depends on where you set your anchor point, but even then, to get from (0,0,40,20) to (0,0,20,40) you would have to also do a translate. And yes, after a transformation, the frame of a view will also be adjusted. However, to be clear, there is no concept of a rotation to a CGRect, it's just an origin and size.